# Appropriate column Match

Tags: excel, vba

[output should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEYGS.png)

I wrote a code which takes the source file copies the data and pastes it in the master file. But there where 3 different workbooks for the data. Now due to the new vendor he gives the data in one workbook but in three different worksheets. What I did was connected the cell range and every time I have to change the cell range according to the data I want to place in that particular row or column. Which is taking time for me to do. I want to automate it fully.

```
Call FillinData(sourceFile, destFile, "Bus", "B42:B53", "L", 10, 12)
```

The above format I was using.

The raw data is in excel format and the excel file has 3 sheets.  I would like to copy this data into master file which also has 3 sheets. So the data for the sheet1 should be pasted into the sheet1 in the master file. And so on for remaining 3.
What I would like my code to do is:

1) Select the raw data.

2) compared the columns of master file and paste it. I would like the code to search the correct column Name in the master file and then paste the values in the correct column from raw file.

My code is here

```
Sub Values()

    Dim sourceFile As String
    Dim destFile As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    sourceFile = "C:\Users\Desktop\Source File Name"
    destFile = "C:\Users\Desktop\Dest File Name"

    Call FillinData(sourceFile, destFile, "Bus", "E57:E68", "D", 7, 12)

End Sub

Public Sub FillinData(ByVal Source As String, ByVal Dest As String, ByVal SheetName As String, ByVal sourceRange As String, ByVal destStartCellName As String, ByVal destStartCellNumber As Integer, ByVal count As String)

    Dim sourceData As Workbook
    Dim destData As Workbook

    Set sourceData = Workbooks.Open(Source)

    For Each C In ActiveSheet.Range(sourceRange)

        Set destData = Workbooks.Open(Dest)

        Worksheets(SheetName).Range(destStartCellName & destStartCellNumber) = C.Value

        destStartCellNumber = destStartCellNumber + 1

        destData.Save

        destData.Close

    Next C

    sourceData.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: I can't see images. Post your question **as text**

Comment: Are you able to see it now?

Comment: Can you [format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) your code ?

Comment: What do you mean by format sir?

Comment: @sam please simplify your problem. It is very detailed and not clear from description and your code. Suggest upload your output and input files with fictitious data but representative data. Things which need clarity are whether your input sheets rows vary time-wise or do they have a consistent pattern that is starting at 6 AM to finishing time. It simplifies a lot . Also you are calling routines a lot many times which seems to be un-necessary. This is just an overview only.

Comment: What I want my code to do:

1) Time period should be displayed from 12:00am, 12:15am………… until 11:45pm ( which my code does it)
2) Copy the data from raw file (In raw file the columns are in different order when compared to master file Also in raw file has couple of columns which master file don’t have. So I only want the columns which are there in master file and eliminate other columns)
3)  As the master file has different order of columns when compared to raw file I would like my code to search for appropriate columns and paste the data of raw file accordingly.

Comment: I need help in point 2 and 3. I am unable match the raw columns data and paste it in appropriate column in master file. And the time pattern varies in different files. That is why I have kept a time window of 12am ---11:45pm . So be any time according to raw data it should automatically search its data and paste in master file.

Comment: I have added all the pictures above. raw file, master file, Output file.

Comment: I have worked out code on sample data for a similar situation as yours. The same column to match in the two Sheets is "Name" row-wise. Further it copies data for columns which have matching headers to Destination Sheet and ignores non matching columns. I have uploaded file to drop box Reference 55339982-want-to-copy-and-paste<https://www.dropbox.com/s/tzesga0dn4l2ul0/55339982-want-to-copy-and-paste.xlsm?dl=0> Please adopt it to your situation.

Comment: Thank you. I will try it and let you know. Appreciate it.

Comment: @sam The code uploaded  is for worksheet to worksheet. I shall workout code from workbook to workbook tomorrow as time permits me.

Comment: Okay thank you so much

Comment: @sam I have uploaded the revised code for workbook to workbook transfer. This should help you progressing with your project. It is a simple approach only as I am hard pressed for time to include more features. Sample source workbook and destination workbooks are contained in a zipped file , upload URL<https://www.dropbox.com/s/u0tij6kg30ufj7d/55339982-want-to-copy-and-paste-V3.7z?dl=0>

Comment: Thank you. I shall look into the code and let you know. Thank you so much for your help and taking time for this. Appreciate it.

Comment: @shakkar: The code works fine for me. I just need to tweak here and there according to my requirements. Thank you for all the help you did.

Comment: @sam I have put my formal answer.Please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something similar to this example should work for you.

```
Sub CopyDest3()

Dim shtImp As Worksheet
Dim shtSrc As Worksheet
Dim wbs As Workbook
Dim wbd As Workbook
Dim k As Integer
Set wbd = ThisWorkbook
Set wbs = Workbooks("Source_1.xlsx") 'presuming workbook is open
Set shtImp = wbd.Sheets("Dest")
k = 1
For k = 1 To 2
Set shtSrc = wbs.Sheets(k)

'From Source to Dest
Dim rngImpTitles As Range
Set rngImpTitles = shtImp.Rows(1)
Dim rngImpNames As Range
Set rngImpNames = shtImp.Columns(1)

Dim CopyColumn As Long
Dim CopyRow As Long
Dim foundRow As Long
Dim foundCol As Long

On Error Resume Next
'for each column in row 1 of import sheet
For CopyColumn = 2 To shtSrc.Cells(1, shtSrc.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    foundCol = rngImpTitles.Find(shtSrc.Cells(1, CopyColumn).Value2).Column
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Not such a col title in importsheet for " & vbNewLine & _
                        shtSrc.Cells(1, CopyColumn)
        Err.Clear
        GoTo skip_title
    End If


    For CopyRow = 2 To shtSrc.Cells(shtSrc.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        foundRow = rngImpNames.Find(shtSrc.Cells(CopyRow, 1)).Row
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            MsgBox "Not such a row name in importsheet for " & vbNewLine & _
                        shtSrc.Cells(CopyRow, 1)
            Err.Clear
            GoTo skip_row
        End If

            If Len(shtSrc.Cells(CopyRow, CopyColumn)) <> 0 Then
                    shtSrc.Cells(CopyRow, CopyColumn).Copy shtImp.Cells(foundRow, foundCol)
            End If

skip_row:
    Next CopyRow
skip_title:
Next CopyColumn
Next k
End Sub
```

Comment: @sam It is bit dificult job matching time formats as regional ie local settings differ. I may be able to try something if you can upload some short sample data of one sheet of both workbooks to be matched. along with correct start row of data. Please separate this exercise from this question and put up a new question which I shall try to look into.

Comment: Ok I will do a seperate question for this along with an image of data.

Comment: "Change of time format and pasting values in particular cell". This is the question which I had posted. Please have a look at it.